# Why is more than my copied link highlighted as a hyperlink when pasting content into scapple?

Tags: scapple

Let's say you want to copy and paste something like this:

*mytotallyoriginallink.com

My totally original notes!*

In Scapple, the note always ends up being messed up, linking part of the notes *after* the link:

***mytotallyoriginallink.com

My tot***ally original notes!

(bold marks the hyperlinked text)

**Why does this happen and how can you avoid it?**

Note: I'm using the Windows version. Here is an example screenshot:
[image: screenshot with notepad on the left side and the scapple result on the right side]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a technical question. This may belong on SuperUser

Comment: According to the [help center](https://writing.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) questions about specialized writing tools are on-topic here. I am voting to reopen the question, though I will add that it might be a good idea to ask on a forum dedicated specifically to this software or ask the company themselves for help. To me this looks like a bug at first glance.

Comment: @Secespitus I thought about that at first but I didn't want to open a new account just to ask one question. If the question is rejected, I'll just go there.

Comment: at least put the name of the software in the title so it is obvious when searching.

Comment: Yes, questions about writing-specific tools are on topic here. Heck, we even have tags for [tag:microsoft-word], let alone [tag:scrivener]. I'm not familiar with Scapple, but if it is a tool typically used by writers and rarely used by others, then asking about it should be on-topic on Writing.

Answer (score 2):

I don’t have this problem, in Scapple on MacOS. Can you add some screenshots?

Is it possible that when you’re adding the link **you don’t have the whole title of the note selected** but just ‘My tot’ and that’s the part of the title that the link is being assigned to?

**To demonstrate:**

Double-Click to add a new note.

Give the note a title, e.g. *My totally original notes!*

**Select the whole title** text with cmd-A, then select from menu, Edit, Add Link:

[image]

Paste your link and click OK.

However, if you just select My tot instead of the entire title, the link will only be associated with that part of it:

[image]

Like this:

[image]

---

Following on from the conversation below. The problem is with Notepad, not Scapple:

Notepad uses a Windows-specific end of line character which combines a carriage return with a line feed. Whereas non-Windows apps will just use one or the other. So, when Scapple sees \r\n it doesn't recognise it as an EOL character. It's expecting either \r or \n. As a result, it sees the link as youtube.comMy and the word example as an extra piece of text.

Comment: So I tried it with Word, the link is correctly marked as a link and the plain text below it stays plain text. Is there a way to change the Notepad line breaks? I really don't want to add another program to my workflow. Right now, it's like this: 1. Copy notes from Google Keep, my main source of notes. 2. Paste them into Notepad to get rid of formatting. 3. Paste them into Scapple. I really don't want to have to add Word to these steps.

Comment: I'd say your best bet is to find another text editor that is Windows compatible but more sophisticated, that's able to recognise links and uses a standard CR or LF as an EOL character.

Comment: Or, this might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15398202/find-and-replace-end-of-line-with-n-verbatim but it still adds another step in your process.

Comment: @noClue You could use the free Notepad++ and then change the general setting for linebreaks like described in [Choose newline character in Notepad++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8195839/7443472). It's a very simple small text editor in its basic form, but with lots of options that you can activate if you want - like the custom end-of-line character.